# Disable writing to Winbond EEPROMs

Tags: eeprom

A common type of EEPROM used in computers is the Winbond chips, such as W25X10A, W25X20A, W25X40A, and W25X80A. [The datasheet for these chips can be found on Datasheet archive](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/WINBOND+25X80AVSIG-datasheet.html#).

It was not clear to me from the datasheet how to hardware protect the chip.

In other words, I want to disable the chip from being written, but not read at the hardware level. Is there any way to do this that is purely hardware based and does not involve sending data to the chip?

Comment: You want something other than the functionality provided by the "Write Protect" pin?

Comment: Using the /WP pin seems too obvious an answer, perhaps you mean protect it in the field but not in the factory. For the latter I suggest a removable jumper, or a DIP switch.

Comment: It was not clear to me how the WP pin was to be used in HARDWARE from the datasheet. The datasheet only describes a software-based procedure for using.

Answer (score 1):

Look on pages 7, 10 and 12 of your Winbond datasheet.

They explain in detail how the /WP pin is used to prevent writes to the Status Register Protect (SRP) bit in the Status Register, preventing the disabling of this bit. This performs the function you describe.